# Check a Boolean value from database at the start of an app then load terms and condition page if false, load menu page if true

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Is this possible?

Before any page loads, could I run JavaScript code to check what the value in a database is, then open the relevant page?

Here is my code so far:

```
function onDeviceReady()    //Phone gap is ready
{
    try 
    {
        db = openDatabase('cuopioid', '1.0', 'cupioids application database',
                2 * 1024 * 1024);
    } catch (e) 
    {
        // Error handling code goes here.
        if (e == INVALID_STATE_ERR) 
        {
            // Version number mismatch.
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Unknown error " + e + ".");
        }
    }
    console.log("DATABASE Created!");
    db.transaction(createTableTerms, errCB, console.log("MEDICINES Table Created!"));
    $('#btnaccept').on('click', acceptTerms);
}
```

The code below creates the database (if it isn't there already)

```
function createTableTerms(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TERMS (id unique, status boolean)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TERMS (id, status) VALUES (0, 0)');
    console.log("TERMS Table Created!");
}
```

I have created this function which selects the rows form the database if it is set to true, then if the results has 1 record I want it to open the menu page, if it has no results it means the terms and conditions haven't been accepted previously:

```
function checkTerms(tx)
{
    db.transaction(function(tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TERMS WHERE status=1', [],console.log("check terms"), errCB);
    });
    var len = results.rows.length;
    if (len = 1)
    {
        console.log("accepted previously - menu page");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("termsandconditions page");
    }
}
```

I am not sure where to put this checkTerms(tx) function

Comment: Is your application public ?

Comment: It will be yes, plan is when the user first downloads the app, they will need to look at the terms and conditions. Once they have accepted them once it will update the database boolean value to true. When they then use the app in the future they wont need to view the terms and conditions, it will load the menu page straight away.

Comment: you shouldn't put sql querying on the client side ! The client will be able to do what ever he want with your database

Comment: It needs to be accessible offline. None of the information would be particularly useful to the client anyway its just a Boolean field for terms and conditions then drug information which is all available free of charge off the internet , if they edited it and broke the app its there problem!

Comment: ha its using the local database ! my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a new JavaScript file which runs when a html page lodes (start of the `<head>` tag

- Which opens the database
- Runs the SQL query to find the value
- Opens the relevant page depending on the result

It still displays the page (half a second at most) when I load the page, but it does what I want

Here is the code:

```
try 
{
    db = openDatabase('cuopioid', '1.0', 'cupioids application database',
            2 * 1024 * 1024);
} catch (e) 
{
    // Error handling code goes here.
    if (e == INVALID_STATE_ERR) 
    {
        // Version number mismatch.
        alert("Invalid database version.");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Unknown error " + e + ".");
    }
}

checkTerms();

function checkTerms(tx)
{
    db.transaction(function(tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TERMS WHERE status=1', [], openPage, errCB);
    });
}   

function openPage(tx, results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length;
    if (len = 1)
    {
        getDrugs();
        window.location.href = "#page1"
        console.log("accepted previously - menu page");
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href = "#page0"
        console.log("termsandconditions page");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this may of been to write a php page as kind of a clearing house based on your database values, then redirect the user to the relevent page. You could do this with ajax and the user wouldn't momentarily see the wrong page either.